# NSSet error when adding record to core data (to-many relationship)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, bundle, accessor

Ok so i'm still quite new to iOS and confused about a few things.
Firstly, here are my entities...
[image: E.R.D]

What i have already in there data wise is a Fruit (Apple) and a Source (Tree). They are both saved in the database.

Next i want to add an orange, but have the relationship with 'Tree'. So this is what i am using:

```
    Fruit *fruit = (Fruit *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fruit" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fruit.fruitName = @"Orange";
  NSSet *test = [NSSet setWithObject:fruit];
    [_source addSourceFruit:test];

NSLog(@"4");

fruit.fruitSource = _source;
```

(_source is the 'Tree', I performed a fetch request for 'Tree' on the Source entity into an array, then took objectAtIndex:0 (Tree) and assigned it to a point towards source entity.

```
   data = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


   Source *_source = [data objectAtIndex:0];
```

and the accessor methods:

```
- (void)addSourceFruitObject:(Fruit *)value;
- (void)removeSourceFruitObject:(Fruit *)value;
- (void)addSourceFruit:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSourceFruit:(NSSet *)values;
```

I have found an answer relating to bundles but i'm not entirely sure about them.
I have read this 'https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html' and 'https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html' but i just don't seem to be grasping it brilliantly.

EDIT: The error is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're confusing Core Data by replacing the `sourceFruit` set.  Core Data maintains inverse relationships.  That means you only have to set `fruit.fruitSource = _source;` for it to understand how the objects are to be connected.  You could use `[_source addSourceFruitObject:fruit];` **instead** but that seems less concise to me.

(Aside: it's a good idea to avoid using the `_name` style of naming for local variables.  It has become something of a standard to use that form for instance variables that back properties.)

Comment: Ok, so by removing the part with the NSSet ( NSSet *test = [NSSet setWithObject:fruit];
    [_source addSourceFruit:test];
) it now throws up 'Problem saving: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)' which means something is blank/nil but i'm not sure what. Sorry mate i dunno how i've landed in such a web haha!

Comment: Given you a tick because the insert seems to work fine, just saving it haha!

Comment: I can't tell from what I'm seeing what that might be.  Instead of logging `@"4"` you might print the values of `_source` and `fruit` to see if there's any clue there.

Comment: Nothing seems to be saying nil, source is <Source: 0x261010> (entity: Source; id: 0x260600 <x-coredata://BA08E406-DE10-4C47-BCE5-403430BA28DF/Source/p4> ; data: {
    sourceFruit = "0x25fdf0 <x-coredata:///Fruit/t3262FDE7-017D-4904-8384-22958E2E4F062>";
    sourceName = Tree;
}) && fruit is <Fruit: 0x25b550> (entity: Fruit; id: 0x25fdf0 <x-coredata:///Fruit/t3262FDE7-017D-4904-8384-22958E2E4F062> ; data: {
    fruitName = Orange;
    fruitSource = "0x260600 <x-coredata://BA08E406-DE10-4C47-BCE5-403430BA28DF/Source/p4>";
})

Comment: This... `sourceFruit = "0x25fdf0 <x-coredata:///Fruit/t3262FDE7-017D-4904-8384-22958E2E4F062>";` ...is saying that sourceFruit is a single object rather than a collection.  My guess is that you converted the relationship from "to-one" into "to-many" in the model but didn't re-generate your Fruit/Source .h/.m files.

Comment: sourceFruit (Sources entity) is showing as an NSSet, fruitSource (Fruit entity) is showing as a singular Source entity. As it is a one to many relationship, i tried re-generating both NSMO Classes just now but to no avail :(

Comment: Something is confused about sets vs. single objects but I'm not sure what.  Can you put another log statement at about the same place as the previous one: `NSLog(@"sourceFruit class: %@", [source.sourceFruit class]);`?

Comment: 2012-12-10 16:40:02.763 E.R.Test[476:707] sourceFruit class: Fruit  (Had to chance source.sourceFruit to _source.sourceFruit as it didn't like it)

Comment: Ya, sorry...I have a mental block against using that underscore.  :-)  Well, you've definitely confirmed the problem.  If I do the same thing in a test project, I get, "`sourceFruit class: _NSFaultingMutableSet`".  I'd be tempted to do a project clean, plus remove the app from the device or simulator and see if a completely fresh build/install changes anything.  If not, I'm not sure what to say; the problem is now obvious but the cause isn't.

Comment: Cocoa error 1570 after cleaning, removing app and doing a fresh build with data.... :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20933/discussion-between-craig-and-phillip-mills)

Comment: So, I understand this thread went on to chat, Did you guys figured out what went wrong? Maybe update the answer with what you guys discussed in chat?